# I need to order items by rank in jekyll

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, jekyll, liquid

So I have a table with scores from a robotics tournament.

My google.yml:

```
teams:
  - rank: 1 
    number: 7854
    name: Midnight Madness 
    qp: 10
    rp: 437
    plays: 5

  - rank: 2 
    number: 7641
    name: MSET Beta Fish
    qp: 10
    rp: 412 
    plays: 5

  - rank: 3 
    number: 12804
    name: LED
    qp: 10
    rp: 302 
    plays: 5
```

https://ibb.co/dtc776

The code for that is:

```
---
layout: pastTournaments
title: Google Tournament
permalink: /tournaments/google/
---

<h5 class="column-wrapper centered">These are the rankings for the Google Qualifying tournament, which was hosted on December 2, 2017.</h5>
<br>
<div class="column-wrapper">
    <div class="grid-x">
        <div class="large-6 shrink cell">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th width="20" class="centered">Rank</th>
                    <th width="150" class="centered">Team Number</th>
                    <th width="150" class="centered">Team</th>
                    <th width="50" class="centered">QP</th>
                    <th width="50" class="centered">RP</th>
                    <th width="50" class="centered">Plays</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
<!--This is where the jekyll starts-->
                    {% assign order = 0 %}
                    {% for team in site.data.google.teams %}
                        {% assign order = order | plus: 1 %}
                        {% if team.rank == order %}
                            <tr>
                                <td class="centered">{{ team.rank }}</td>
                                <td class="centered">{{ team.number }}</td>
                                <td class="centered">{{ team.name }}</td>
                                <td class="centered">{{ team.qp }}</td>
                                <td class="centered">{{ team.rp }}</td>
                                <td class="centered">{{ team.plays }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor%}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

I need to have it so it stacks when I change my `.yml` file's rank, like if I swap 1 with 2 and 2 with 1. The two just go away like this:
https://ibb.co/kq0ifR

How do I make it so that that it reorders when I change a rank in my `.yml` file?

Note: I do have some other unimportant zurb stuff that's why the columns aren't closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sort` liquid filter.

```
{% assign sorted = site.data.google.teams | sort:"rank" %}
```

and then : `{% for team in sorted %}` ...